# expanding functions with logs to find Big-O estimate

Tags: asymptotics, logarithms

```
 Please could someone advise on the two questions below. I have to expand the functions
 first. Admittedly, I have a weak understanding of logs. Then I try to ascertain a 
 Big-O estimate. Any help would be appreciated. 

 1.) (nlogn + n^2)(n^3 +2)

 Expanding the above.. Is it correct to say
 nlogn(n^3) + nlogn(2) + n^2(n^3) + n^2(2)

 ==> n^3 (due to the cancellation laws) +2nlogn + n^5 +2n^2
 ==> therefore a Big-O estimate would be n^5 ??

 2.)  nlog(n^2 +1) + n^2logn
  expanding the above ..is it correct to say
  2nlogn + nlogn + n^2logn
  As n<n^2logn<n^2, 
  the Big - O estimate is (n^2)?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first problem, the dominant term is $n^5$, so it's $O(n^5)$.  On the second one, your dominant termis $n^2\log(n)$ so it is $O(n^2\log(n))$.

Comment: thx ncmathsadist